# How to associate subsection meta-data in SOLR searchable text

Tags: solr, metadata

I'd like to make the text of a book searchable in SOLR, and I'd like to include the page number(s) where the matching text can be found in the original book.

I'm wondering what mechanisms SOLR might have to associate a page number with the searchable words of text?  (To be clear, I'm talking about the page number of the original source text, not anything to do with SOLR result pagination.)

So in essense I basically need to have structured text, whereby each searchable word (ideally each letter actually, because my real use-case is more of a giant substring that may start anywhere within the word) has some associated meta-data.  I could put this information in an external datastore if necessary, but wondered if SOLR has a way to do it natively.

If not, is there another tool better suited to this purpose than SOLR?

Comment: Payloads allows you to attach metadata to tokens themselves: See the following Lucidworks article for an example: https://lucidworks.com/post/solr-payloads/ - that might work for what you need. Sadly I don't have the time right now to make a more complete example of how it could work.

Comment: Not a direct answer, hence a comment. When you are interested in creating a book full text, checkout [Hathi Trust's Blog](https://www.hathitrust.org/blogslarge-scale-search) about it. Maybe aged in some parts, but the concepts should hold true.